# Fixed points for finitary distributive lattices bijection

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory

Birkhoff's Fundamental Theorem of Finite Distributive Lattices says that there is a bijection
$$ \{ \textrm{finite posets}\} \to \{ \textrm{finite distributive lattices}\} $$
$$ P \mapsto J(P), $$
where $J(P)$ is the set of order ideals of $P$, ordered by containment. The inverse of this bijection sends a lattice to the induced subposet on its set of join-irreducible elements.

It is easy to see that $\# J(P) > \#P$, so this bijection has no fixed points.

There is an extension of the FTFDL to certain infinite, but not too infinite, distributive lattices. Namely, we say that a distributive lattice is *finitary* if it is locally finite (meaning all intervals are finite) and has a minimum. Then there is a bijection
$$ \{ \textrm{posets with all principal order ideals finite}\} \to \{ \textrm{finitary distributive lattices}\} $$
$$ P \mapsto J_{\mathrm{fin}}(P), $$
where $J_{\mathrm{fin}}(P)$ is the set of finite order ideals of $P$. Again, the inverse sends a lattice to its join-irreducible elements.

Notice that $\mathbb{N} \simeq J_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N})$, where $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,\ldots\}$ is the natural numbers with its usual total order. So unlike the finite distributive lattice bijection, the finitary distributive lattice bijection has a fixed point.

**Question**: Are there other fixed points of the finitary distributive lattices bijection, besides $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $P\cong J_{\mathrm{fin}}(P)$ and $P\not\cong \mathbb{N}$.
Now $P$ is a distributive lattice, so (since every order ideal is
finite) it has a unique minimal element (of rank 0). Let $k$ be the least
positive integer such that $P$ has more than one element of rank
$k$. Then $J_{\mathrm{fin}}(P)$ has just one element of rank $k$, a
contradiction.

Thus a better question might be to require that $P$ be isomorphic to
$J_{\mathrm{fin}}(P)$ with its minimal element removed. Then there is
the poset consisting of a finite chain $x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ with two incomparable
elements $y_1,y_2>x_n$, and an infinite chain $z_0<z_1<\cdots$ lying
above $y_1$ and $y_2$. Possibly there are no further examples.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466941/are-there-more-than-2-types-of-posets-p-cong-mathcal-o-rm-finp-setminus/466942#466942

Comment: One can find more examples at the above link.  I am guessing that, except for adding some elements with unique lower covers at one specific level (with consequences for the higher ranks), that may be it.