# Are there more than 2 types of posets $P\cong\mathcal O_{\rm fin}(P)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: posets

We use notation derived from Davey and Priestley, *Introduction to Lattices and Order*. Let $\mathcal O_{\rm fin}(P)$ be the poset of finite down-sets of the poset $P$. A finite poset is *ranked* if all maximal chains have the same size.

On this page
[Fixed points for finitary distributive lattices bijection](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466664/fixed-points-for-finitary-distributive-lattices-bijection)
someone with the pseudonym "Richard Stanley" wrote: "a better question might be to require that $P$
be isomorphic to [$\mathcal O_{\rm fin}(P)$]
with its minimal element removed. Then there is the poset consisting of a finite chain $x_0<x_1<⋯<x_n$
with two incomparable elements $y_1,y_2>x_n$, and an infinite chain $z_0<z_1<\cdots$ lying above $y_1$
and $y_2$. Possibly there are no further examples."

Are there further examples?

Richard Stanley (https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley), Fixed points for finitary distributive lattices bijection, URL (version: 2024-03-08): https://mathoverflow.net/q/466666

Comment: [I don't think that's a pseudonym.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_P._Stanley)

Comment: I agree with @NoahSchweber. Judging from the [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley) of Richard Stanley, he seems to be the real (famous!) Stanley.

Comment: "Nom de guerre", then?

Answer (score 2):

One could argue there are actually infinitely many examples (or at least there is a larger family of examples).

Given a finite, ranked poset $Q$ and $k\ge0$, let $Q_{\le k}$ be the poset of elements of rank at most $k$ and let $Q_k$ be the poset of elements of rank $k$.

**Theorem 1.** Let $P$ be a finite ranked poset of rank $r\ge1$.  Assume that $\phi:P\cong\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+1}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and assume that $D\subseteq P_{\le r-1}$ for all $D\in\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+1}$.

Then there exists a finite, ranked poset $Q$ of rank $r+1$ such that $P=Q_{\le r}$ and there exists an order-isomorphism $\psi:Q\cong\mathcal O(Q)_{\le r+2}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ extending $\phi$ such that $E\subseteq Q_{\le r}$ for all $E\in\mathcal O(Q)_{\le r+2}$.

*Proof.* Let $X$ be a set such that $P\cap X=\emptyset$ where $\eta:X\to\mathcal O(P)_{r+2}$ is a bijection.  Let $Q=P\cup X$. For $p\in{\rm Max}\ P$ and $x\in X$, let $p<x$ in $Q$ if and only if $\phi(p)\subseteq\eta(x)$.

**Claim.**  The poset $Q$ is a finite ranked poset of rank $r+1$.

*Proof of claim.* Any $E\in\mathcal O(P)_{r+2}$ is such that $E=D\cup\{w\}$ where $D\in\mathcal O(P)_{r+1}$.

Let $x\in X$ be such that $\eta(x)=E$ and let $p\in P$ be such that $\phi(p)=D$.  Thus $p<x$ and $p\in{\rm Max}\ P$.

Also, given $p\in{\rm Max}\ P$, let $D:=\phi(p)$. Since the ranked poset $\mathcal O(P)$ contains an element of cardinality at least $r+1$, $|D|=r+1$ and $D\subseteq P_{\le r-1}$.  Since $P_r\ne\emptyset$, $P\supsetneqq D$ and $P\in\mathcal O(P)$, so there exists $E\in\mathcal O(P)$ such that $E\supsetneqq D$ and $|E|=|D|+1$.  Thus $E\in\mathcal O(P)_{r+2}$ so there exists $x\in X$ such that $\eta(x)=E$ and $p<x$.

Hence $Q$ is ranked of rank $r+1$. $\diamond$

Let $\psi=\phi\cup\eta:Q\to\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+2}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ extend $\phi$.  It is an order-isomorphism.

Assume for a contradiction that $E\in\mathcal O(Q)_{\le r+2}$ but $E\nsubseteq Q_{\le r}$.  Then $E\cap Q_{r+1}\ne\emptyset$.  Since $Q$ is ranked of rank $r+1$ and $|E|\le r+2$, $E$ is an $r+2$-element chain.

Thus $E\cap P\in\mathcal O(P)$ is an $r+1$-element chain so $E\cap P\in P_{\le r-1}$; hence $|E\cap P|\le r$, a contradiction.

This also shows that $\mathcal O(Q)_{\le r+2}=\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+2}$. $\diamond$

**Corollary 2.** Let $P$ be as in the statement of Theorem 1.  Then there exists a poset $T$ such that for all $t\in T$, $\downarrow t$ is finite and ranked and for all $k\ge0$, the set of elements of $T$ of rank $k$ is finite and the set of elements of rank at most $r$ is $P$ and $T\cong\mathcal O_{\rm fin}(T)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.

*Proof.* We have a commutative diagram with left edge the inclusion map from $P$ to $Q$, right edge the inclusion map from $\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+1}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ to $\mathcal O(Q)_{\le r+2}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, bottom edge $\phi$ and top edge $\psi$, since $P=Q_{\le r}$.

Let $T$ be the filtered limit of the filtered system $P^{(0)}:=P$, $P^{(1)}:=Q$, $\dots$.  Let $\phi^{(\ell)}:P^{(\ell)}\cong\mathcal O(P^{(\ell)})_{\le r+1+\ell}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ for $\ell\ge0$. (See Lemma 4.5 and Proposition 4.1 of https://cgasa.sbu.ac.ir/article_103580_7e019629f987fc8498db5f7b71403816.pdf .)

Define $\sigma:T\to\mathcal O_{\rm fin}(T)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ as follows: For $t\in T$, take any $\ell\ge0$ such that $t\in P^{(\ell)}$ and let $\sigma(t)=\phi^{(\ell)}(t)$.  It is an order-embedding.

Let $E$ be a finite non-empty down-set of $T$.  Then there exists $\ell\ge0$ such that $E\subseteq P^{(\ell)}$ where $|E|\le r+\ell+1$, so $E\in\mathcal O(P^{(\ell)})_{\le r+\ell+1}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.  There exists $p^{(\ell)}\in P^{(\ell)}$ such that $\phi^{(\ell)}(p^{(\ell)})=E$.  Thus $\sigma$ is onto. $\diamond$

**Corollary 3.** Let $r,s\ge2$.  Let $P$ be the poset ${\bf r-2}\oplus\mathcal P(\{1,\dots,s\})_{\le 2}$.
Then $P$ satisfies the conditions of Theorem 1.

*Proof.* If $P$ has elements $x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_{r-3}<y<z_1,\dots,z_s$, where $\{z_1,\dots,z_s\}$ is an antichain, then $\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+1}\setminus\{\emptyset\}=\big\{\{x_0\},\{x_0,x_1\},\dots,\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3}\},\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3},y\},\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3},y,z_1\},\dots,\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3},y,z_s\},
\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3},y,z_1,z_2\},\dots,\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{r-3},y,z_{s-1},z_s\}\big\}\cong P$.

Also, each $D\in\mathcal O(P)_{\le r+1}$ is a subset of $P_{\le r-1}$. $\diamond$